# Can't get R to read GPS coordinates

Tags: r, google-maps, gis

I imported a CSV file of about 50 GPS coordinates into R, and I'd like to plot them on GoogleMaps. I've used the plotGoogleMaps library and coordinates() and proj4string() functions. I've also used the get_map() and plot() a lot, but my points aren't showing up?

My first problem was that my GPS coordinates were in lat,lon format instead of lon,lat format when being plotted. But they're still not showing on a map.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your data, e.g.   `dput(head(YOUR_DATA_HERE)`     That will make it much easier for others to understand and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: What's about using QGIS for your task and search for related topics on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ too?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, or what you've specifically tried using those functions, it's impossible to help you very much. Check out the [Tips on Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Try running str() on your data frame, hopefully the columns containing the coordinates are numeric. If not it might be the data types you got when you imported the data.

Going out on a limb based on your newness to R, try using stringsAsFactors = FALSE when you read in the csv.